# How do i get only unique href elements in selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to extract all the href links in an anchor tag using selenium for my web scraping project in python.

I have multiple pages on a single page and I am trying to access the href elements for a single page.

Below is the code:

```
url = "https://www.carwale.com/used/cars-for-sale/#sc=-1&so=-1&pn=1"

driver.get(url) 

links=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@href]')

for l in links:
    print(l.get_attribute('href'))
```

On running my code the same href element gets printed multiple times.

Snippet of Output of the code:

https://www.carwale.com/used/cars-in-chennai/ford-figo-2010-2012-d2115418/?slot=4&rk=1&isP=true

https://www.carwale.com/used/cars-in-chennai/ford-figo-2010-2012-d2115418/?slot=4&rk=1&isP=true

https://www.carwale.com/used/cars-in-chennai/ford-figo-2010-2012-d2115418/?slot=4&rk=1&isP=true

How do I get it to print only once?

Comment: sir, show your code here!

Comment: The code is there, but not very well-formatted. Next time, format your post, so others can help you easier.

Comment: it is hard to paste the code from jupyter notebook here

Answer (score 0):

Do something like:

```
url = "https://www.carwale.com/used/cars-for-sale/#sc=-1&so=-1&pn=1"

driver.get(url) 
processed = []
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@href]')
for link in links:
    if link not in processed:
        print(link.get_attribute('href'))
        processed.append(link)
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: I tried doing the same thing but it is  still printing the same thing

Comment: hi @Noah i have figured it out

Comment: how about you rewrite your issue with the solution you found?